# Array task. Finding last two negative numbers in array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, search, negative-number

Search for the numbers of the last two consecutive negative elements in an array. The length of the array is entered from the keyboard. Float type.

my code is:

```
import math
import numpy
import random
#i = (random.uniform(-1000, 1000))
o = []
a = []
n = int(input())
n += 1
l = 0
sh = 1
m2 = n
m = n-1
m=int(m)
for i in range(n):
    x = (random.uniform(-1000, 1000))
    a.append(x)
for i in range(m):
    otric = a.pop(m)
    otric = int(otric)
    a.insert(otric,int(m+1))
    if otric < 0:
        o.append(otric)
        m -= 1
        if len(o) > 2: break
print(a)
print(o)
```

and this doesn't work, idk how to fix it.. please help

Comment: Either start from the end of the array or reverse the array and start from the beginning of the reversed array, it seems simpler to me that way. I would be tempted to have a list of the negative numbers, initially empty. When a positive number is encountered, empty the list. When a negative number is encountered, append it to the list and check the length of the list. If the length is 2 then you're finished.

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` to get all consecutive negative numbers and return the last element of the resulting list:

```
a = [random.uniform(-1000, 1000) for _ in range(n)]
>>> [(x,y) for x,y in zip(a, a[1:]) if x<0 and y<0][-1]
(-696.9270891497699, -612.4999984966855)
```

Comment: Or [`itertools.pairwise(a)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) instead of `zip(a, a[1:])`

Comment: Why `import` anything when it's not needed?

Comment: @not_speshal: Why write your own code and risk getting it wrong when someone else has already written it, and has written it to be more space efficient.

Comment: @FrankYellin - Good for you if you think `import itertools` and `itertools.pairwise(a)` is more concise than `zip(a,a[1:])`. Also `zip` is not me writing my own code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try it later!

Comment: @not_speshal.  `a[1:]` creates a new array.  `itertools.pairwise()` doesn't.   I did also mention "more efficient, spacewise", didn't I?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the list in reverse and when a value is negative also grab the next one and see if it is the pair we're looking for:

```
lst = [1, -7, -8, 1, 1, -1, 1, -2, -3, 1, -4, 1, -5, 1, 1]

it = reversed(lst)
for a in it:
    if a < 0:
         b = next(it, 0)
         if b < 0:
             print(b, a)
             break
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try it later!

Comment: Did you find the time to try?